# Using Amazon Cognito's Authorization Code Grant with Serverless/Single-Page Web Application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm attempting to develop a serverless JavaScript web application consisting of API Gateway (w/ an Amazon Cognito Custom Authorizer), Lambda, and DynamoDB. This post is my last attempt to make Cognito work for my needs before completely giving up on it (for a 2nd time). I'll try to infuse a bit what I've learned since the Cognito documentation is confusing and lacking.

With Cognito, you can develop a custom authentication workflow with your own registration, sign in, etc. web pages. You also have the option to leverage Amazon's Hosted Web UI to make things a bit simpler (although with very few HTML/CSS customization options). *I'm using the latter.*

When configuring an App Client for a Cognito User Pool, the most critical decision you have to make is whether to use an Authorization Code Grant or an Implicit Grant. With an Authorization Code Grant, a successful authentication will return a session token containing a JWT id_token, access_token, and refresh_token to your caller. With an Implicit Grant, your caller will receive an Authorization code that can be used to obtain an id_token and an access_token only, with no refresh_token. The Implicit Grant is most suitable for serverless (or single-page) applications because it won't expose a long-lived refresh_token to the client which can be easily compromised and used to assume valid access to your application. However, the access_token has a fixed expiration of one hour that cannot be configured at this time. So, without a refresh token to silently renew the access_token, your user will have to log-in every hour.

Since my web application in no way contains sensitive information, I'm going to use the Authorization Code Grant and persist the tokens in the browser's LocalStorage (***which is unsafe, not recommended, and a bad practice***) in hopes that, at some point, Cognito will fully comply with the OpenId Spec and provide full support for [refresh tokens with implicit grants via prompt=none](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/92). As you can see, Amazon has been unresponsive on the matter. Heck, even an option to customize the expiration time of the access_token (with Implicit grant) would be a nice compromise.

So I've successfully deployed the sample application from the [amazon-cognito-auth-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/tree/master/sample) JavaScript library, which is meant to be used with the Hosted Web UI flow. This should not be confused with the amazon-cognito-identity-js library, which should be used if you're developing your own custom authentication workflow. The amazon-cognito-auth-js library supports both the Authorization Code Grant as well as the Implicit Grant and will handle parsing the tokens, caching/retrieving them to/from LocalStorage, and silently renewing the access_token with the refresh token (for Authorization Code Grant).

When I sign-in, my browser URL resembles the following: https://www.myapp.com/home?code=ABC123XYZ... and the three JWT tokens are set in the browser's LocalStorage. If I immediately refresh the page, however, I receive an "invalid_grant" error, because the Authorization code is still in the URL and has already been consumed. Should I just do a page redirect upon successful sign-in to remove the Authorization code from the URL? Here's the main code at play which I plan to call fromthe onLoad() of every page in my app:

```
function initCognitoSDK() {
        var authData = {
            ClientId : '<TODO: your app client ID here>', // Your client id here
            AppWebDomain : '<TODO: your app web domain here>', // Exclude the "https://" part. 
            TokenScopesArray : <TODO: your scope array here>, // like ['openid','email','phone']...
            RedirectUriSignIn : '<TODO: your redirect url when signed in here>',
            RedirectUriSignOut : '<TODO: your redirect url when signed out here>',
            IdentityProvider : '<TODO: your identity provider you want to specify here>', 
                    UserPoolId : '<TODO: your user pool id here>', 
                    AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag : <TODO: boolean value indicating whether you want to enable advanced security data collection>
        };
        var auth = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoAuth(authData);
        // You can also set state parameter 
        // auth.setState(<state parameter>);  
        auth.userhandler = {
            onSuccess: function(result) {
                alert("Sign in success");
                showSignedIn(result);
            },
            onFailure: function(err) {
                alert("Error!" + err);
            }
        };
        // The default response_type is "token", uncomment the next line will make it be "code".
        auth.useCodeGrantFlow();
        return auth;
    }
```

Comment: You can either redirect to remove the code from query string or check on page load if your app can find a valid access token in the browser local storage and, in that case, ignore the code received in query string

Comment: Thanks, @SébastienStormacq. In my onLoad, I added the following conditional: 

if ( auth.getCachedSession() != null && auth.getCachedSession().isValid() ) {
 console.log("already valid");
} else {
 var curUrl = window.location.href;
 auth.parseCognitoWebResponse(curUrl);
}

If you add your comment as an answer, then I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either redirect to remove the code from query string or check on page load if your app can find a valid access token in the browser local storage and, in that case, ignore the code received in query string.